# Laravel : How can I modify auth:sanctum middleware to return a 401 instead of redirect to login route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum, sanctum

Good evening,

I encounter a problem using Laravel and Sanctum to build an Api for a Mobile application.

I followed the documentation and define a route to get a token :

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
 
Route::post('/sanctum/token', function (Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'device_name' => 'required',
    ]);
 
    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
 
    if (! $user || ! Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' => ['The provided credentials are incorrect.'],
        ]);
    }
 
    return $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;
});
```

Tested it with postman, everything works fine, if I pass the right login and password, I'm able to get my token.

Now the problem I'm facing : I protected a route as the documentation said by using this middleware :

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get(' ....'
```

If I pass my token in headers, it works, but if I don't, Laravel tries to redirect me to /login route, which I don't want of course because I'm creating a mobile application.
** What I want is to receive a 401 if my token isn't valid. **

I tried to define a new middleware and copy the verification of the 'auth:sanctum' but I can't even find where this is defined, since it is not in the Kernel.php file.

I hope someone could explain me how I could find the code of 'auth:sanctum', so I can understand it and create a middleware with the comportement I need, but any help would be appreciate.

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: pass the header to accept JSON with the requests you are making

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks you, please do a real answer so I can validate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recently experienced the same issue.

You are likely sending the `Accept: application/json` header with your request in Postman. This tells Laravel that the route is being access as an API route, rather than a web route and so returns a json response with 401.

When you omit the header, the application assumes you are making a standard HTTP request from a web route. As you are not authenticated for web it simply redirects you back to the login route.

If you are writing tests, you can use the `getJson` and `postJson` methods for the API routes.

Comment: Thanks you for taking time so much time after, I forgot to write the answer many month ago but yes, that was it.